# Pentaho BI Server - Action Sequence - Failed to execute

Tags: report, pentaho

Ok, first... Sheesh. I know I should have this but it just isn't clicking.  I've read through the user guide, a few books on Pentaho in general and of course, posts here on this site.  Something ain't clicking though so your patient "you poor newbie" help is much appreciated.

Now, down to business...

I'm running Pentaho BI Server 3.9.0 both on a Mac (10.6.8) and a Centos 5 server. (Trying in different enviro's to confirm the issue.) Same results in both sites.

I've published some reports from PRD 3.8.3-GA-Stable and when I open them in the BI Server (by way of web interface) they behave with no errors and the report appears accurate. They are in the same folder as the xaction.

The file structure is:

```
    ... biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions
        |- Example
          |- Followed_Data.prpt
          |- example.xaction
```

When I create an action sequence by way of the design-studio to execute the report, the error included below continually appears.  I've destroyed the xaction file a few times and tried different things and it just isn't happening.

Thoughts and jovial slaps upside the head would be appreciated; this has been frustrating.

Thanks in advance!
-Lorin

XML Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action-sequence> 
  <title>Example</title>
  <version>1</version>
  <logging-level>ERROR</logging-level>
  <documentation> 
    <author>Lorin</author>  
    <description>Empty blank action sequence document</description>  
    <help/>  
    <result-type>report</result-type>  
    <icon/> 
  </documentation>

  <inputs/>

  <outputs/>

  <resources> 
    <TotalFollowedReport> 
      <solution-file> 
        <location>Followed_Data.prpt</location>  
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type> 
      </solution-file> 
    </TotalFollowedReport>  
    <report-definition> 
      <solution-file> 
        <location>Followed_Data.prpt</location>  
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type> 
      </solution-file> 
    </report-definition> 
  </resources>

  <actions> 
    <action-definition> 
      <component-name>SimpleReportingComponent</component-name>
      <action-type>Pentaho Report</action-type>
      <action-resources> 
        <report-definition type="resource"/> 
      </action-resources>
      <action-outputs> 
        <outputstream type="content" mapping="FollowedData"/> 
      </action-outputs>
      <component-definition> 
        <outputType><![CDATA[text/html]]></outputType>  
        <useContentRepository><![CDATA[true]]></useContentRepository> 
      </component-definition> 
    </action-definition>

  </actions> 
</action-sequence>
```

Error:on

The Pentaho BI Platform reported an error while running an action sequence

Possible Causes:
null
RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - Action failed to execute
Action Sequence:example.xaction
Execution Stack:
EXECUTING ACTION: Pentaho Report (SimpleReportingComponent)
Loop Index (1-based):0
Error Time:Sunday, February 19, 2012 1:33:51 PM EST
Error Type:ActionExecutionException
Session ID:lorin
Instance Id:44ece1f6-5b28-11e1-bf5e-295c39ace768
Action Class:SimpleReportingComponent
Action Description:Pentaho Report
Hide Details
Stack Trace:

```
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ActionExecutionException: RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - Action failed to execute
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1308)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1262)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1161)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1105)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:987)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:897)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:399)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:317)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:193)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.BaseRequestHandler.handleActionRequest(BaseRequestHandler.java:159)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.ViewAction.handleActionRequest(ViewAction.java:167)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.ViewAction.doGet(ViewAction.java:316)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.PojoComponent.executeAction(PojoComponent.java:429)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.ComponentBase.execute(ComponentBase.java:463)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1293)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Looking through the errors you get, and not being that big a Pentaho expert, I would guess that there might be some kind of permissions problems with the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after the weekend I have a fresh attack and figured out a number of my issues.

I was trying to write an Action Sequence to only schedule a report execution. That was easily fixed by logging into the PUC and using the File > Manage > Schedule feature and identified the job.

My intimated question has also been answered over the last 24 hours of head -> wall therapy and that was if there was any good doc's that would help getting action sequences figured out.

I found a number of useful documents but the breakthrough occurred with a "Creating Action Sequences" pdf (could only find it at: http://wenku.baidu.com/view/84ac804c767f5acfa1c7cdb8.html). This site details the different object types and includes a working example of the "outputstream" that is required to make report outputs proper.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.pentaho-japan.com/pentaho/docs/creating_action_sequences.pdf) the one?

Comment: The link goes to a chinese site ?!?!